# Message passing between two machines on a network

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, distributed-computing

**Problem description:** There are two processes running on two different Unix machines in a network. What is the simplest way to pass a simple message, for example "Hi!!", from one machine to another? I know there are many methods of IPC, but what is the simplest one with minimal overhead?

Is Boost MPI useful in my scenario? I am using C++ for my implementation.

Comment: UDP / TCP connection and send some bytes

Answer (score 2):

Sockets. Here is a sockets [tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). Once you have a hang of sockets, you can also use [boost sockets](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html#boost_asio.tutorial.introduction_to_sockets)

Comment: why can't I use Boost:MPI cause I just need to pass a small message ?

Answer (score 2):

Use sockets (I would advice boost sockets) or have a look at [ZeroMQ](http://zguide2.zeromq.org/cpp%3ahwclient). ZeroMQ might actually be easier as it guarantees to always receive the complete message.

Answer (score 1):

Is this simple enough? (using pure MPI standard calls without any 3rd party libraries like `Boost.MPI`)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
   // Initialise the MPI library
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

   int rank, size;
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

   if (size != 2) {
      if (rank == 0)
         cout << "ERROR: You must run this program with 2 processes" << endl;
      MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);
   }

   if (rank == 0) {
      // Rank 0 sends the message
      string hi = "Hi!";
      MPI_Send((void*)hi.c_str(), hi.length()+1, MPI_CHAR,
               1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
   else {
      // Rank 1 receives the message
      // Probe for a message and get its actual size
      MPI_Status status;
      MPI_Probe(0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      int len;
      MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_CHAR, &len);
      // Allocate buffer space for the message and receive it
      char *message = new char[len];
      MPI_Recv(message, len, MPI_CHAR,
               0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
      cout << "Rank 1 received: " << message << endl;
      delete [] message;
   }

   MPI_Finalize();

   return 0;
}
```

Compile with `mpic++ -o mpihi.exe mpihi.cc` and execute:

```
$ mpiexec -np 2 ./mpihi.exe
Rank 1 received: Hi!
```

The code could be simplified if the length of the message is fixed in advance. It could be possible to further simplify it using `Boost.MPI` but I have never used it so I cannot provide you with an example.

The nice things of MPI are its guaranteed message delivery and the way it abstracts the specifics of the interconnect. You can change the placement of the two MPI processes by providing the appropriate options to `mpiexec`. If both processes are placed on the same physical node, shared memory would be used to communicate the message. If placed on different nodes, some network mechanism would get used.

Of course, it all depends on your needs. MPI libraries are complex pieces of code with a lot of supporting infrastructure, e.g. you need to run your code through a dedicated launcher program (in most cases `mpiexec` or `mpirun`) and you cannot use MPI to simply connect two random processes (i.e. you really *have* to launch them both via `mpiexec`/`mpirun`).

Comment: Thank you for your example ,please can you explain that if I want to send message from process "new" running on Machine "A" to process "publish" running on Machine "B" , so MPI will be useful or sockets or some other mechanism

Comment: If both processes are started independenly (e.g. they are system daemons started by the `init` mechanism), then it might be very hard to integrate MPI in this scenario. Otherwise you can send whatever you like inside an MPI message. MPI even supports heterogeneous environments and most implementations can convert message data on the fly between different internal representations, e.g. a big-endian 64-bit machine can transparently send integers to a 32-bit little-endian machine.

Comment: my processes are not daemons , It's actually like Process "new" running on machine A should invoke process "publish" on machine B, so a simple message like publish.exe should run on machine B called via machine A

Comment: Sounds like you also want to perform remote launches. MPI supports spawning additional processes at run-time and provides means to communicate with them. You still need to run through `mpiexec` though.

Comment: Exactly I want remote launch of "publish" process and communication between them , Please can you suggest me some good tutorial which gives me idea to implement this problem in c++

Comment: The dynamic process management feature of MPI is often considered an advanced topic. You can find a simple basic example [here](http://etutorials.org/Linux+systems/cluster+computing+with+linux/Part+II+Parallel+Programming/Chapter+9+Advanced+Topics+in+MPI+Programming/). You can then futher research on the the topic.